# How to deal with the garbled characters about PDF file on Ubuntu?

Tags: pdf, ubuntu

I have searched this method:

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-data
```

But also,when I download a PDF file from my Ubuntu server,it's character is garbled:(

I haven't restart my server.Is it necessary?

Comment: What's the "programming" problem here?

Comment: No,I have tried on CentOS last month.That's ok.But now on Ubuntu isn't ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command

```
sudo mv /etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf.backup
```

to try.

Or this method:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf
```

Change the **sans-serif**(At the below of the file line -4) to others and restart your X.